# How can I implement data validation in a ribbon textbox in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I'm updating an old app to use a ribbon.  In one place the old version has a button that opens a small dialog to take a numeric value from the user.  I'm trying to use `CMFCRibbonEdit` to replace it with a textbox on the ribbon.  The dialog I'm attempting to replace used DDX/DDV to control the user input.  Since the ribbon is hosted in `CMainFrame`, I thought I would just have to use the class wizard to add a `DoDataExchange` override to the main frame; and then add a copy of the DDX/DDV code from the dialog and just update the data member/id/etc values.  However after doing this, my `DoDataExchange` method isn't being called when I do any editing of the contents of the textbox or leave its focus, nor are the input value restrictions being enforced.

```
void CMainFrame::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CFrameWndEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CMainFrame)
    DDX_Text(pDX, ID_CALIBRATE_USER_DEFINED_EDIT, m_CalDistance);
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_CalDistance, 0, 9999);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DoDataExchange/UpdateData is a virtual function inside CWnd but it is never called for a CFrameWnd or CToolBar or CMFCMfcRibbonBar.

You can simply override CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl::OnKillFocus and manage all your validation here. But you have to do it manually.

It may be possible to get UpdateData to work, but in this case the parent of your ribbon edit control has to execute UpdateData, otherwise the control ID isn't found. Keep in mind that I wouldn't expect dialog messages when I enter something in a ribbon. I would expect that the data is automatically changed to its minimum or maximum.

Comment: If I was overriding methods in the edit control, I'd need to do more than just OnKillFocus.  I'd need to fiddle with one that fires before each keystroke is processed to toss any non-numeric characters.  `CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl` is more or less undocumented in MSDN (basically just "don't screw with it") so how would I find what I need to change; and since it's not something I'm creating directly how would I force the framework to use my override.  Would I need to derive a custom version of `CMFCRibbonEdit' to host my modified `CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl` and create them without using the designer?

Comment: Uhm, no. [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/19/115912.aspx).

Comment: I agree to IInspectable with dialogs. Inside a single control it is different. Also I would correct the information and would avoid error messages.
For change events use OnEditChange in your ribbon edit control.